# Multiple command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I've been studying a little bit of Python and I came across the `getopt` module for parsing command-line arguments.

Basically, I've got the following code:

```
import sys, getopt

print("The list of %s arguments passed:" % len(sys.argv))

# Print each argument
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
print()

# Now print parsed arguments
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "ab:cd", ["arbitrary", "balance=", "cite"])
for opt in opts:
    print(opt)
print()

# Print the arguments returned
print(args)
```

However, I need the `-b` option to take two different arguments, E.g `-b one two`. I've tried putting two colons after the `b` in the argument list of `getopt`, but it didn't work.

If someone can tell me how to do this using the `getopt` module and post examples it would be really useful!

Comment: Note that `getopt` is deprecated; use the far more versatile [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead. It supports multiple values per option.

Comment: Related read - [PEP 0389](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) which has mentioned [deprecation of `optparse`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/#deprecation-of-optparse) and [de-emphasized `getopt`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/#updates-to-getopt-documentation)

Comment: use `argparse` and surround the argument with double quotes `-b "argument with spaces"`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahhhh, I didn't know that! Sometimes I forget I'm reading 'Dive Into Python' which was written a few years ago... Perhaps if you made your comment into an answer I'd accept it as the main answer :)

Comment: @MatGomes Why don't you divide the `-b` in two arguments ?

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks! I'm reading this article right now!

Comment: @PedroLobito I guess I could do that, but I just wanted to know if there's a way of getting multiple arguments for a parameter

Comment: @MatGomes : it's possible with Docopt; have a look to the answer I wrote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget getopt, use **[Docopt](http://docopt.org/)** (really):

If I understand well, you want user to pass 2 arguments to balance. This can be acheived by :

```
doc = """Usage:
   test.py balance= <b1> <b2>
   test.py
"""

from docopt import docopt

options, arguments = docopt(__doc__)  # parse arguments based on docstring above
```

This program accepts : `test.py balance= X Y`, or no arguments.

Now if we add 'cite' and 'arbitrary' options, this should give us :

```
doc = """
Usage:
   test.py balance= <b1> <b2>
   test.py

Options:
   --cite -c           Cite option 
   --arbitrary -a      Arbitrary option   
"""
```

The program now accepts options. 
Example :

```
test.py balance= 3 4 --cite

=> options = {
    "--arbitrary": false, 
    "--cite": true, 
    "<b1>": "3", 
    "<b2>": "4", 
    "balance=": true
}
```

**tip**: in addition, you can [test your documentation string directly in your browser](http://try.docopt.org/) before using it in your code.

Life saver !

Comment: I'm currently looking into the argparse module, I'll have a look at the docopt  module once I've understood argparse . Which one is supposed to be better/simpler? argparse or docopt?

Comment: @MatGomes [Python - Difference between docopt and argparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599513/python-difference-between-docopt-and-argparse)

Comment: I learned argparse, then Docopt. And I realised that I'd learned argparse for nothing, because Docopt is straightforward, you don't have to learn an API, you just have to learn (if you don't already know it) a standard. This is also used in Linux man pages so you should be used to it.

Comment: If you're looking for really (really) more complicated things, you can have a look to [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/)